# Обход многомерного массива без рекурсии

Tags: php

Задан многомерный массив, в каждой ноде есть минимум одно поле name.

Нужно реализовать поиск по этому массива, и вернуть найденный элемент с заданным названием. Т.е.

```
function &findNodebyName(array &$tree, string $name) {
    foreach($tree as &$node) {
        if($node["name"] == $name)
             reutn $node;
    }
}
```

Сейчас эта функция обходит массив (по корневым элементам), и находит элемент с  `$node["name] == $name` и возвращает ссылку на нее.

Нужно как-то эту функцию переписать, чтобы обходил массив не только по корневым элементам, а еще и по вложенным `$node["chids"]`, вложенность может быть любая. Создавать доп. массив или модифицировать текущий нельзя, также доп. ограничением (которая для меня стала ключевой - из-за которой не могу реализовать алгоритм) - это нужно решить без рекурсии.

Comment: идете по уровню массива, сами элементы обрабатываете, в вложенные скидываете в доп массив. Потом идете по этому доп массиву, сами элементы обрабатываете, вложенные снова скидываете в доп. массив. Будет у вас обход в ширину без рекурсии.

Comment: можно пример пожалуйста, не совсем понимаю, как обходить дочерние подмассивы любого уровня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
function &findNodebyName(array &$tree, string $name) {
    $nodes = [&$tree];
    $i = 0;

    while($i < count($nodes)) {
        foreach($nodes[$i] as &$node) {
            if($node['name'] == $name) {
                return $node;
            }

            if(array_key_exists('children', $node)) {
                $nodes[] = &$node['children'];
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Создавать доп. массив или модифицировать текущий нельзя - но из танка конечно виднее.